# How to make equal 5 columns in bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have to create 5 columns in a row but sometime it may be less than 5 columns in a row, how can i manage this?

My Code:-

```css
.col {
  border: solid;
  margin: 2px;/* this can be added without breaking the row */
}
.col:before {
content:attr(class);/* show class used */
color:crimson
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    
<div class="w-100"></div>

    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>

<div class="w-100"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

For example:- Right now How can i manage last two boxes, i want all the boxes should equal like first row boxes width...

Thank You!

Comment: Instead of `col` try using `col-2` as class or else you can use percentages too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want all columns to always be the same width as the columns in the first two rows. If that is correct, you could just override the `max-width` property on Bootstrap's `col` class.

Something like this (using your unchanged HTML):

```css
.col {
  border: solid;
  margin: 2px;
  /* this can be added without breaking the row */
  max-width: 18% !important;  /* added. note, if you remove the margin above, you could set this to 20% */
}

.col:before {
  content: attr(class);
  /* show class used */
  color: crimson
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>

    <div class="w-100"></div>

    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>

    <div class="w-100"></div>

    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You may also wish to set a constant width for all columns using the `width` property. But I may be misunderstanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you are using bootstrap 4+ then you can achieve without using *<div class="w-100"></div>* extra element and without write single line of css code too.

Comment: @RaeeshAlam True, I just used the same markup as the OP in case he had the element there for some other purpose.